# How to connect onClick events on website with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to design a Virtual Piano. All my sounds of individual keys are stored in MongoDB. How to play the particular key sound when the user clicks it??
I tried making all keys as buttons atop the piano image and assigning ids to each key. And then using get request, used findById() of mongoDB to find that key sound. But it doesnt seem to play.

Comment: so what is actual problem, whether you not receiving data from mongo db, or you have received data you need from mongoDb but its not producing sound? you will also wanted to add sample code or link to the code if you want the answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.